# jenkins parameter that can run scripts and list results

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, azure-cli

Is it possible to have a parameter that can execute a script and put the results in a drop-down list, like choice?

For example, if I have 3 string parameters:

- username -> some account used to login to azure
- password -> some password
- subscriptionId -> some id

With this information, it would be possible to run something like:

```
az login -u username -p password
az accounts set -s subscriptionId
az group list --query "[:].name"
```

and get all the resource groups from that subscription. Now I can display them in the select box and let the user of the build select the resource group instead of going to the portal and copy-pasting it into Jenkins.

Is something like this achievable?

Comment: If the scope of your question is, "How do I populate one of the job Parameters with a result of complex query against external servers", you can achieve that by using ActiveChoice plugin and lots of Javascript. This is achievable but very hard.

Comment: I would love it to be Javascript, but I believe it is groovy? And yes, the question is exactly that. I don't mind it is hard, but I would love to see an example and some documentation as well. I am familiar with Active Choices but even though it provides some cool features, I feel like I can't do what I'm asking here. I thought of using az cli and making commands like: 'az etc'.execute() and capture the output. But that feels really out of the ordinary let's say.